# How to minimize cost function define over volume omega using BFGS algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, optimization, scipy-optimize

Engineer and Mathematician programmer,

I have computed a cost function J(x1, ..xn, t) and its gradient J'(x1, ..xn, t) defined over a volume using finite element analysis at each increment of time t in [0, T].

So I have the value of these fields J and J' at n nodes (x1, ..xn) at each increment of time in the geometry and I have saved the data in a text file.

My problem is how to minimize this function using, for example, the BFGS algorithm.

Comment: This is an interesting question, however, since you say you have computed J at each point, it seems like you can just look for the minimum value of J. If that doesn't work for you, maybe you can clarify the problem statement to say why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much, dear Robert for your response. To simplify the question: how to minimize a function represented by a vector of value and its gradient also define itself as a vector of value? the two vectors vary with each increment of time. I hope you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward if you use [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def my_cost_function(x):
    # Your computation returns both cost and its gradient
    return cost, gradient

my_initial_guess = ...    # Your initial solution estimation
result = minimize(my_cost_function, x0=my_initial_guess, method='BFGS', jac=True)
```

The `result` variable is an [OptimizeResult](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult) object with information about the result or its absence.

Comment: Thanks for your replay the function is defined by value at each point (xj) not define explicitly and his value also depends on time ti (0=<ti<=T).
We can look at J and J' as a vector. and for each ti we have new value of J(xj) and J'(xj)